# bash script code to create .tar.gz to a specific file extension

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting.I have a requirement, find out or list .bak(it shld be only .bak, shouldn't select other .bak.tar.gz files while listing) files and then compress them and create .tar.gz files.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these code helps. `*.bak` will match all `.bak` files.

```
tar -czf example.tar.gz *.bak
```

Comment: Thanks. But my requirement is it suppose to list the .bak files first and convert them one by one according to the file name. ex; abc23jan2013.bak ro abc23jan2013.bak.tar.gz. In case if I already have abc23jan2013.bak.tar.gz, this file shouldn't be recreated as abc23jan2013.bak.tar.gz.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You probably needs this :

```
#uncomment 1 of the next 2 lines : the first DOES the cmd, the 2nd only echo it

#thecmd="tar"
thecmd="echo tar"

export thecmd

for bakfile in ./*.bak ; do
   [ -f "${bakfile}" ] && ${thecmd} -czf "${bakfile}.tar.gz" "${bakfile}" 
done
```

This also test if the file is a REGULAR file (and not a dir, or a pipe, or a block device) before compressing it into file.tar.gz (note: try to avoid reserved words and variable names in your variable names. There are quite a lot)

Comment: if you need to compress files at different sublevels (subdirs), you could : `for bakfile in $(find . -type f -name '*.bak' -print) ; do [ -f "${bakfile}" ] && tar -czf "${bakfile}.tar.gz" "${bakfile}" ; done` (but this will choke if find replies with some names/dirs with space or other special characters in them... unlikely on a unix system, but it does happen. Then you need more magic.)

Comment: I guess I have to replace filename with 'bakfile' everytime to create the .tar.gz file? If so it's not possible as I have number of files in my directory. I was trying with the below script which created .tar.gz files which are present in a folder, one by one with file name. "cd /backup/location
for i in `ls`; do tar -czvf /backup/location/$i.tar.gz $i; done". But the issue is it's creating .tar.gz for all the files. But I would like to convert only files which has got .bak extension. Thanks

Comment: to try my 2 examples: just replace "tar" with "echo tar" and you'll be able to see what command would be launched, and on what file(s). It does what you asked for (it does, for *each* "file.bak" a "file.bak.tar.gz" compressed tar archive of it. and only on *.bak files.

Comment: you can also, if needed, put the .tar.gz archives in another location : just replace "${bakfile}.tar.gz" by "/backup/location/${bakfile}.tar.gz"

Comment: and to be very clear : when you ask "I guess I have to replace filename with 'bakfile' everytime to create the .tar.gz file?", no : the "for bakfile in ./*.bak" does it for you (assuming the *.bak files are in the current directory). just "cd" to the directory the .bak files reside in, before launching the comamnd.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will check and let you know.

Comment: I edited it out so it's simpler to test it and run it (either uncomment one or the other line so that "thecmd" contains the real command you want to start). start as it's shown, it will only echo what it would do. Then comment the 2nd lien/uncomment the 1st line defining thecmd. you have to run this from the directory containing the *.bak files.

Comment: careful with this : the parenthesis are sometimes written sometimes omitted : don't try changing either ways until you see why it was written that way (ex: in the for loop, the only one not quoted is ${thecmd} so that it works even if thecmd contains more than 1 word (as it does, when it contains "echo tar", for example) ... Just copy/paste the whole thing.

Comment: Thank You very much  Olivier. Your script worked fine. Thanks for the help.